# Qt Connect Unable to Connect to Slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I have no issues with connecting signals to slots in Qt until I met this issue. I am unable to connect to the slot when I clicked on my tool button (btnNR).

The slot calls another widget to be shown. I am quite certain the connect signal is correctly formatted. However, the slot is not called. Can anyone please help?

SetMalDlg.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtGui>

class SetMalDlgInjRem;

class SetMalDlg : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SetMalDlg(void);
    ~SetMalDlg(void);
    SetMalInjRem *malInjRem;

public slots:
   void slot_SetMalDlgInjRem();

public:
   void createLayout();
   ...
};
```

SetMalDlg.cpp:

```
#include "SetMalDlg.h"
#include "SetMalDlgInjRem.h"

SetMalDlg::SetMalDlg(void)
{
    malInjRem = new SetMalDlgInjRem;
    createLayout();
    connect(btnNR, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot_SetMalDlgInjRem()));
    setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
}

SetMalDlg::~SetMalDlg(void)
{
    disconnect(btnNR, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot_SetMalDlgInjRem()));
}

void SetMalDlg::createLayout()
{
    ...

    // create btnNR here

    ...
}


void SetMalDlg::slot_SetMalDlgInjRem()
{
    malInjRem->show();
}
```

SetMalDlgInjRem.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtGui>

class SetMalDlgInjRem : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SetMalDlgInjRem(void);
    ~SetMalDlgInjRem(void);

public:
   void createLayout();
   ...
};
```

SetMalDlgInjRem.cpp:

```
#include "SetMalDlgInjRem.h"
#include <QtGui>

SetMalDlgInjRem::SetMalDlgInjRem(void)
{
    createLayout();
    setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
}

SetMalDlgInjRem::~SetMalDlgInjRem(void)
{
}

void SetMalDlgInjRem::createLayout()
{
    this->resize(1033, 452);
    labelMalInjRem = new QLabel(this);
    labelMalInjRem->setText("Text");
    labelMalInjRem->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 301, 31));

    ...
}
```

Comment: Show your header code. Have you declared them as public slots: %or something?

Comment: @AlexandreTryHardLeblanc: I have included my header codes. Yes, I have declared `slot_SetMalDlgInjRem()` as public slots and included `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: have you tried with clean project, qmake again and then build and run?

Comment: @Tab: I have cleaned and rebuild the project. Now it works fine, although I am not sure what happened.

Comment: instead of writing the solution in the question, accept the answer bellow

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine you have to just clean project, qmake and then build. Since you have edited code but did not qmake it so meta object compiler was not properly invoked to update changes in moc generated files and hence slot was not actually connected.